# using a flip toggle switch with angularjs and jquery mobile

Tags: jquery, mobile, angularjs

How to use a flip toggle switch with AngularJS and jQuery Mobile?

The following snippet contains a flip toggle switch that does not get selected by angular and a commented checkbox that does get checked by angular:

```
<div data-role="content">
  <ul id="pumps" data-role="listview">
    <li ng-repeat="pump in fleetManager.pumps"
      ngm-click="fleetManager.toggleBuzzer(pump)"><span>{{pump.sn}}</span>
      <span>
        <!-- FIXME: does not select the marked option -->
        <select data-role="slider">
          <option value="silent">Silent</option>
          <option value="beeping" ng-selected="pump.status!=0">Beeping</option>
        </select>
        <!-- NOTE: this one works as expected -->
        <!--input type="checkbox" ng-checked="pump.status!=0"-->
    </span></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

adding an `ng-model` attribute to the `<select>` tag got it working:

```
<select data-role="slider" ng-model="somemodel">
    <option value="silent">Silent</option>
    <option value="beeping" ng-selected="true">Beeping</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

Found that controls do not integrate well in list-views.
Changed the design.

Answer (score 0):

i developped a open source directive(bootstrap).
You can use it to do this, 
see doc : https://github.com/timactive/angularjs/tree/master/directive/ng-switch-toggle
you can view a sample : http://plnkr.co/Qo7QtmFbrEsCbEOauDvY.